# Multi-Dimensional Stacked Bar Chart in Flot

Tags: flot

This question is very similar to [Multi-Dimensional Stacked Bar Chart with ZingChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726417/multi-dimensional-stacked-bar-chart-with-zingchart).  (I am trying to replace ZingChart, which requires a license, with Flot, which does not.)

I have 4 "dimensions" that I want to show in a stacked bar chart:
1 - Sales
2 - Year: 2000 and 2001
3 - Product: P1, P2 and P3
4 - Region: North and South

The x-axis will be Year for this example, but note that I am using categories in Flot, so the solution must work with categories.

The values will come from Sales.

The stacks in each bar chart will show the sales for each Product.  For each year there will be a bar for each Region. (Region is therefore the fourth "dimension".)

So it will be a total of 4 bars (2 regions x 2 Years), and 3 stacks per bar (for each product), like this:

```
Region   Region    Region   Region
North    South     North    South  
 P1       P1        P1       P1   
 P2       P2        P2       P2
 P3       P3        P3       P3

    2000                2001
```

I have successfully created a "three dimensional" stacked bar chart with just Sales, Year and Product, following:  [Jquery Flot category stacked bar chart not stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185514/jquery-flot-category-stacked-bar-chart-not-stacking)

Comment: Try the [Side by side plugin](https://github.com/pkoltermann/SideBySideImproved). And show your work (for example as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you have further problems.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you show me what sample data would look like with four "dimensions"? I'm not sure how that would be done.